# Updating single column for some records take too long

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 200 records. But some of the record updations takes too long.

Explain analyses return this for update single column for the single record:

Update on res_users  (cost=0.27..2.29 rows=1 width=436) (actual time=1725978.705..1725978.705 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using res_users_pkey on res_users  (cost=0.27..2.29 rows=1 width=436) (actual time=0.054..0.094 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = 151)
 Planning time: 1.435 ms
 Execution time: 1725979.468 ms

Comment: Not 100% sure, but If you have trigger(s) on that table, trigger execution takes time. Check foreign keys/indexes these can also slow down insert or update.

Comment: What's the query? In addition to previous suggestions are you sure it wasn't waiting for a lock to be released by another process. Is this consistent if run multiple iterations?